# How to get selected cells from an office ribbon control

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2010

I want to get the active range from a ribbon control. There should be a way to access the selected cells ONLY when a control on the ribbon needs it.

Currently this is how I am doing it;

```
public partial class ThisAddin
{
    private void SheetSelectionChange(object sh, Range target)
    {
        int count = target.Count;

            if (count < 5000) // This is for performance reasons 
            {
                //Set a custom range property in the office ribbon
                Req_Tool.ActiveRange = target; 
            {
    }
}
```

I feel this is weak and wasteful.
Firstly, EVERY time a selection changes my code is run. 
Secondly, I have two copies of the selection wether its used or not.

There has to be a better way to do this that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the currently selected range in the active sheet by accessing the `Selection` property of the `Application` object.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveRange = (Excel.Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
}
```

MSDN documentation:

- [ApplicationClass.Selection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.applicationclass.selection%28v=office.14%29)
- [Application.Selection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214188%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Previously this would only select the first cell in the collection for me. I realized that when specifying type explicitly as a range. You must make it a *List<Range> selectedCells* or a var.  I think this is worth stating. Of course this seems obvious now... Go Stack!